# How to install Ubuntu server 19.10 on orange pi 3?

Tags: boot, server, system-installation, arm, arm64

I have a [Orange pi 3](http://www.orangepi.org/Orange%20Pi%203/) , I have tried to install Ubuntu server 19.10 (arm64 version ) on my board but it was unsuccessful:
I wrote ubuntu-19.10-live-server-arm64.iso on a TF card via balena Etcher. Then I put the card in its slot and powered on the board, but Das u-boot just booted default android tv (installed from factory on board) and didn't boot the fedora image. I deleted Das u-boot and android tv partition using `fdisk` on orange pi modified version of ubuntu 16.04 Xenial. I retried booting Ubuntu server 19.10 from card but the board just showed processor (Allwinner H6) logo and froze in this level.

I tried installing ubuntu mate 18.04.2 arm64 version but it had same result as ubuntu server.

At the end I took the TF card out an when I restart the borad saw the allwinner logo again that means the borad didn't recognized those medias as bootable media!

I really need help installing Ubuntu 19.10 server on my board.

**note:** all of iso files hashes are checked and they were healthy files

Answer (score 1):

Did you use the images as supplied by orange pi or did you take the images from the main website and just chose the arm image?

http://www.orangepi.org/downloadresources/OrangePi3/2019-01-23/orangepi3_b0c3dac8d3483dab6eb392b0a9.html

This is the image you should be using.

Mind you. Orange pi offers very limited support so if you are up for it it might be better to customise something from scratch.

Comment: The image in the link is Ubuntu 20.04 (focal), but I think you're right that this image has to be used.